# What is exactly to handle event in react component?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a component to **promote reusability**. In this component, I am handling the post submitting event when submitting form and I want to show status like success/error message if this post submitting was succeed/failed.

I am thinking of two ways to handle the `onAddPost` submitting event and show the status success/error:

**1. Handle directly at the `AddPost` component:**

*./components/add-post.js (children component):*

```
function AddPost ({ onAddPost }) {
   
   const submitHandler = async (data) => {
     try {
       await onAddPost(data); 
       toastify('Add post successfully!'); // show success message 
     }
     catch (err) {
       toastify(err); // show error message
     } 
   }

   return (
     <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      ...
     </form>
   )
}
```

*./pages/add-post.js (parent component):*

```
...
const { addPost } = usePost();
<AddPost onAddPost={addPost}/>
```

**2. Handle directly at the parent component (otherwise known as pages component or container component):**

*./components/add-post.js (children component):*

```
function AddPost ({ onAddPost }) {
   
   const submitHandler = async (data) => {      
       onAddPost(data);          
   }

   return (
     <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      ...
     </form>
   )
}
```

*./pages/add-post.js (parent component):*

```
...
const { addPost } = usePost();

const addPostHandler = async (data) => {
     try {
       await addPost (data); 
       toastify('Add post successfully!'); // show success message 
     }
     catch (err) {
       toastify(err); // show error message
     }       
}

<AddPost onAddPost={addPostHandler}/>
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to improve my case to `promote reusability` AddPost  component by two ways above?

Comment: If its a common component / reusable component and the `onAddPost` should behave the exact same way , better to write it inside the component. But If `onAddPost` may change as per how parent component wants to handle things, then better approach is let the parent handle the `onAdd` and the component `AddPost ` just raises the event to its parent. And there is no ONE best way to `promote reusability`. Its always what the use of the component is.

Comment: @RohitKhanna  I am very grateful for your help. But can you provide to me an example about "`onAddPost` may change as per how parent component wants to handle" ? I really need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them are ok but I think second one is better, because there might be a case that you want add a post in AddPost component but don't want to show toast (redirect to another page or etc) so in second pattern you wont faced any challenge. and it also obey [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), it means that  AddPost component just needs to have a form and call function addPost (not handing errors or etc)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really need coffee right now!